# Cutting Python List with Mass

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list like,

```
defaultdict(list,
            {37.0: ['C22H27O7',
              'C21H23O8',
              'C25H35O7',
              'C24H31O8',
              'C23H27O9',
              'C22H23O10',
              'C21H19O11',
              'C20H15O12',
              'C19H11O13'],
             111.0: ['C22H27O7',
              'C19H15O10',
              'C25H35O7',
              'C22H23O10',
              'C24H31O8',
              'C21H19O11',
              'C23H27O9',
              'C20H15O12',
              'C19H11O13'],
             74.0: ['C21H23O8',
              'C19H15O10',
              'C25H35O7',
              'C23H27O9',
              'C24H31O8',
              'C22H23O10',
              'C21H19O11',
              'C20H15O12',
              'C19H11O13'],
             148.0: ['C25H35O7',
              'C21H19O11',
              'C24H31O8',
              'C20H15O12',
              'C23H27O9',
              'C19H11O13'],
             185.0: ['C25H35O7', 'C20H15O12', 'C24H31O8', 'C19H11O13'],
             222.0: ['C25H35O7', 'C19H11O13']})
```

and I have a calculateMass function which is

```
def calculateMass(formula):
    if(formula[0:1] == "C"):
           # print(add[k]1:3)
        C = int(formula[1:3])
        C = C*12000    
        print(C)
    if(formula[3:4] == "H"):
        H = (int(formula[4:6]))
        H = H*1008
    if(formula[6:7] == "O"):
        O=(int(formula[7:9]))
        O=O*15995
    total = O + C + H
    print(total)
```

My aim is cut myList with respect to Masses for example my desired output should be:

> [1] 37  --> C22H27O7--> C21H23O8 (Cut From here because next
>   element's mass [C25H35O7] > [C21H23O8])
>
> [2]  37 --> C25H35O7 --> C24H31O8 --> C23H27O9 --> C22H23O10 -->
>   C21H19O11 --> C20H15O12 --> C19H11O13  (Since masses are decreasing we
>   do not need to cut.)

and Iterate over other key values

> [1] 111 --> ......

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: First, I suggest you use regexp to handle the parsing. Your current way of using index to parse the string is not very flexible. What happen "C1000O200"?

Comment: Can I also suggest you clarify what myList actually is? In the beginning you write "I have a list like,", followed by a defaultdict, which is not a list. I assume that myList is actually the dictionary, but it would help writing a better answer if you could clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only want the output (and not another data structure with the split lists), you could iterate over the lists of formulas, comparing each value `calculateMass(myList[index][i])` with the previous one `calculateMass(myList[index][i-1])` like this:

```
for index in myList:
    count = 1
    print("[", count, "]", index)
    print(myList[index][0])
    for i in range(1,len(myList[index])):
        if calculateMass(myList[index][i]) > calculateMass(myList[index][i-1]):
            count += 1
            # print("-- cut --")
            print("[", count, "]", index)
        print(myList[index][i])
```

Comment: Sorry I did not mention, I need to store my output, how can I store in dataFrame such as rows are 37, 111 ... and the value of columns are the chemical formulas. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what your myList looks like, but assuming that it is just a list of formula strings, you could do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict

group_dict = defaultdict(list)
for item in my_list:
    group_dict[calculateMass(item)].append(item)
```

That way, you will get a dictionary whose keys will be the masses and its values will be lists of formulas.

You can then iterate over the dictionary's keys with

```
for key in sorted(group_dict.keys()):
    print(key, group_dict[key])
```

to print the sublists sorted by their masses.

If you want to do this for each of your original dictionary's lists, I would suggest you put the whole thing in a function and call it for each list you want to process.

Comment: I am getting an error because in default dict I can not use append() method.

Comment: @teamzealot Sorry, my bad. There was an obvious bug. Fixed it. Also this assumes that my_list is a list of formulas. If you want to iterate over the defaultdict in your original post, you have to add another loop that iterates over your dictionary's values. Let me know if you need an example for that.